# What are some methods of testing data analytics systems and ETL processes?

Tags: sql, mapreduce, bigdata, etl

I work primarily with so-called "Big Data"; the ETL and analytics parts. One of the challenges I constantly face is finding a good way to "test my data" so to speak. For my mapreduce and ETL scripts I write solid unit test coverage but if there are unexpected underlying changes in the data itself (coming from multiple application systems) the code won't necessarily throw a noticeable error which leaves me with bad / altered data that I don't know about.

Are there any best practices out there that help people keep an eye on what / how the underlying data may be changing?

Our technology stack is AWS EMR, Hive, Postgres, and Python. We're not really interested in bringing in a big ETL framework like Informatica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create some kind of mapping files(maybe xml or something) as per the standards specific to your systems and validate your incoming data before putting it into your cluster, or maybe during the process itself. I was facing a similar issue sometime ago and ended up doing this.

I don't know how feasible it is for your data and your use case but it did the trick for us. I had to create the xml files once(I know it's boring and tedious, but worth giving a try) and now whenever I get new files I use these xml files to validate the data before putting it into my cluster to check whether the data is correct or not(as per the standards defined). This saves a lot of time and effort which would be involved if I have to check everything manually everytime I get some new data.

Comment: Can you give an example of some of the checks that you put in your mapping files?

Comment: Number of fields, their dataypes, value ranges(as some values must lie within a particular range) etc etc.